# File is not saving with Http request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I need to save file to directory in solution and save its path to database as string. But neither file is saving to file directory, and consequently its path as well. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code of Controller POST method:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("addBank")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddBank([FromForm] Bank bank, IFormFile file)
        {
            file = Request.Form.Files.FirstOrDefault();
            await imageUploadService.UploadFile(file);

            await bankRepository.Add(bank);
            return Ok(bank);
        }
```

And service that saves file:

```
public class ImageUploadService : IImageUploadService
    {
        public IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment;

        public async Task<string> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
        {
            
            try
            {
                if (file.Length == 1 && file.ContentType == "image/png")
                {
                    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file.FileName);
                    Bank bank = new Bank();
                    var newFileName = "Logo_" + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Milliseconds + fileInfo.Extension;

                    string fileLocation = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "/UploadedFiles/" + newFileName));
                    if (!Directory.Exists(fileLocation))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(fileLocation);
                    }
                    
                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(fileLocation, file.FileName), FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                        bank.Logo = fileLocation;
                    }
                    return fileLocation;
                }
                else
                {
                    return "Ошибка при сохранении файла";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Ошибка при сохранении файла", ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You trying to call `Directory.Exists(fileLocation))` on path that is including the file name `newFileName`. Use debugger to check what your code is performing.

Comment: Remember that `Path.Combine` will take care of ..\ in a path, meaning that somebody could choose to upload a file to a directory above your root upload folder.

Comment: Is the file exists in imageUploadService?And can you share you the data of `Path.Combine(fileLocation, file.FileName)`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Modify the file.Length == 1 to file.Length > 0 as Length is the file length in bytes.
2. The Directory.Exists() checks whether directory exists in a location. However you are passing the directorypath + filename to it which is incorrect.